# `wide-exec-charset` dose not change the charset of `wchar_t`

Tags: c++, g++, c++17

Here is the simple C++ code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main() {
    std::wcout.sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::wcout.imbue(std::locale(""));
    std::cout << std::locale("").name() << std::endl; // C.UTF-8
    
    wchar_t s {L'\xd0b8'};
    std::wcout << s << std::endl;
    // expected: и
    // actual: 킸
}
```

- `'\xd0b8'` is `и` in UTF-8 and is `킸` in UTF-16

The [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) mentioned:

> The encoding of narrow multibyte string literals (1) and wide string literals (2) is implementation-defined. For example, gcc selects them with the commandline options -fexec-charset and -fwide-exec-charset.

I complied and executed the code with `g++ -O3 -fwide-exec-charset=UTF-8 source.cc -o out.a && out.a` in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (WSL) and expected the output is `и`, however, the actual output is `킸`. g++ doesn't treat the hex in the literal string which was used to directly initialize the wide char `s`. How to make g++ consider the wide char in UTF-8?

System Infomation:

```sh
> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
> g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
```

Comment: `-fwide-exec-charset=UTF-8` doesn't make a lot of sense. If you want a wide character encoding, you select a wide-character encoding like UTF-16, not a multibyte encoding like UTF-8. In fact you should never use any wide character anything. It is outdated technology born by bad decisions made by Microsoft and Sun back when.

Comment: I am just testing `wchar` and try to understand how it works. I know `wchar` is not portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`man gcc` says

```
  -fwide-exec-charset=charset
       Set the wide execution character set, used for wide string and character
       constants.  The default is UTF-32 or UTF-16, whichever corresponds to the width
       of "wchar_t".  As with -fexec-charset, charset can be any encoding supported by
       the system's "iconv" library routine; however, you will have problems with
       encodings that do not fit exactly in "wchar_t".
```

UTF-8 is a multi-byte encoding which does not fit exactly in `wchar_t`. So you've got exactly what is specified in the documentation: problems. Since `sizeof(wchar_t)` on Linux is 4, you need to specify a 4-bytes-wide encoding such as UTF-32.

There is no real reason to use `wchar_t` for anything except interfacing with legacy code anyway.

Comment: After changing `L'\xd0b8'` to `L'\x00010437'`(`` in UTF32BE) and compiling with `-fwide-exec-charset=UTF32LE`, the preprocessor still uses UTF32BE to decode `L'\x00010437'` and print ``. It seems that `-fwide-exec-charset` is not worked with 4-bytes-charset like UTF32LE either.

Comment: `\x00010437` is a number. It is represented as the same bit pattern whatever charset is used. Try `L''`, you will see that it produces different bit patterns depending on `-fwide-exec-charset`. You will also see that only with `UTF32LE` the output is ``. This is because the standard library has no idea that your particular source file is compiled with a special `-fwide-exec-charset`. It is not a program-wide option. The standard library still interprets wide characters as UTF32LE. If you want your whole program to work in UTF32BE, you will need standard library recompiled with UTF32BE.

Comment: Or I guess you can use an appropriate `std::codecvt<wchar_t, ...>` facet.

Comment: After trying your suggestion changing `L'\x00010437'` to `L''`, I finally realized that the charset given with `-fwide-exec-charset` is the target charset of the conversion from source files to `wchar_t`. However, I am curious about is recompiling the standard library with UFT32BE the only way to change the charset used by `wcout` to read the bytes in `wchar_t` and where is the corresponding source code located? I have explored `libstdc++v3` in gcc's repository for hours, but I can't find the code converting UFT32LE to the charset set with `imbue`.

Comment: There is probably no such code, if you need this conversion you have to provide your own. Why do you need this though? Use what works, that is, `char` and UTF-8.